# Publish android app with advertising and without advertising

Tags: android, publishing

I want to publish an android app in he google play store in two modes:

The first free but with advertising. The second without advertising but the user have to pay. It is the same application but the difference is the ads.

Way is the best option to achieve this?

1 - One application that hides ads with a property? (app property, database property, etc)

2 - Two differents apps?

3 - Other solution?

Many thanks

All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it in one project and use the Google in-app payments to manage the full version. If you have two separate apps people can just buy the full version, extract the .apk and then get a refund. That way they didn't pay anything and have the full version. They then can pass the .apk to anyone else.
In-app purchases are bound to the Google account, this does give you some security.

Answer (score 2):

I done it as 3 projects: one contains core project with additional hook and interfaces and two which implement end user application based on core. Technically it's looks like registering additional listeners for ads and IAP

I would recommend you keep it as one application with IAP so user can get rid of ads without losing any data and hustle. It's also good for google play rating as you'll have cumulative number of downloads and reviews

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with all of my applications and I find that it's definitely better to keep it all in one application. With Android it's possible for your applications to be ripped after purchase and spread around for free without other users having to pay. Of course this isn't what you want so the way I get around this is to develop only one application. Inside that application have a managed in-app purchase that will remove ads. When the application is running, before displaying the ads, check to see if they have purchased the remove ads item and if they did don't show the ad. This stops you from having to repeat code and separate into different projects.

Answer (score 2):

I should create one app, and create an unlocker for it to hide the ads. Most of the time you will see that some people will pay for your app once and then distribute it for free online. As you can see on the Google Play Store, there are a lots of apps, but if you want the full features you need to buy an unlocker. This kind of protection is much better compared to publishing two seperated apps.